# JDBC choose NIC to use based on local ip address?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver on a machine that has multiple network cards. Only one of them has a stable connection. Is there anyway to tell JDBC to use that NIC by giving it the IP address of the NIC?

Comment: It's not generally possible on most operating systems *at all* to directly select a NIC. Your best option (and I don't know if this is doable with JDBC, but it's the place to look) is setting the socket source address explicitly.

Comment: You'd usually need to correctly configure this on the OS level by defining routes for destination addresses, etc. Trying to solve this in Java is the wrong place (if it were even possible, and I don't think it is).